# How can I display a token from contextual filter

Tags: panels, views, tokens, navigation

I am trying to see if there is a way to pass basically  a contextual token to a panel page. I have a panel page which displays Views blocks of content types based on contextual filter of author real name, but I would like to also generate another block or custom content to display elsewhere on the panel page which displays the author real name and maybe some other profile items.

Is there any way to pass the contextual filter from the view into this type of content?

I have been able to expose the author name, but only as a list which has one entry for each article rather than a field which I could use as a header, etc.

I'm probably missing something basic here, but any help would sure be appreciated. My experience to date has mostly been with displaying current user name, etc. in custom blocks or other content.